# NA || TRUE vs NA || FALSE - R

Tags: r, logic, na

This is more of an abstract question about R, but observe the following behavior:

```
NA || TRUE
# [1] TRUE
NA || FALSE 
# [1] NA
```

This seems inconsistent... NA is ignored in the first case, but takes precedence in the second case. Also, how could one implement a truth function or overload the || operator to create the desired behavior below:

```
NA || TRUE
# [1] TRUE
NA || FALSE 
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: `any(NA, FALSE, na.rm = T)`

Comment: The behavior seems consistent to me. `NA | TRUE` is certainly `TRUE`, irrespective of the value that could be replaced by `NA`. However, the result of `NA | FALSE` is undefined since it depends on whether the missing value is `TRUE` of `FALSE`.

Comment: Indeed, I would never want `NA || FALSE` to return `FALSE`, as that would be, well, wrong.

Comment: Also, as stated in `?Logic`: _...Where a component of x or y is NA, the result will be NA if the outcome is ambiguous..._

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot. I wasn't thinking about substitutions at all. Anyway, thanks y'all

Comment: There's a recent and very apropos blog entry just released about this: http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-trick-to-understanding-nas-missing-values-in-r/, where a key phrase is *"think of `NA` not as a number, but as a **placeholder** for a number that exists, but whose value we don't know*". In the first case, it doesn't matter which boolean value the `NA` takes, the expression is always true so the `NA` value is moot. Not so with the second expression.